# Laravel 5.2 Missing required parameters for [Route: showtopic] [URI: theme/{id}/topics/{id}]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I keep getting the following error:

`Missing required parameters for [Route: showtopic] [URI: theme/{id}/topics/{id}].`

This is what my Web.php looks like:

**Everything regarding topics in web.php**

```
Route::get('/theme/{id}/topics/{id}', 'TopicsController@show')->name('showtopic');

Route::get('/theme/{id}/topics/{id}/edit', 'TopicsController@edit')->name('edittopic');
Route::patch('/theme/{id}/topics/{id}/edit', 'TopicsController@update')->name('updatetopic');

Route::get('/theme/{id}/topics/create', 'TopicsController@create')->name('createtopic');
Route::post('/theme/{id}/topics/create', 'TopicsController@save')->name('savetopic');

Route::delete('/theme/{id}/topics/{id}/delete', 'TopicsController@destroy')->name('deletetopic');
```

**Everything regarding themes in web.php**

```
Route::get('/theme/{id}/topics', 'ThemesController@show')->name('showtheme');

Route::get('/theme/{id}/edit', 'ThemesController@edit')->name('edittheme');
Route::patch('/theme/{id}/edit', 'ThemesController@update')->name('updatetheme');

Route::get('/theme/create', 'ThemesController@create')->name('createtheme');
Route::post('/theme/create', 'ThemesController@save')->name('savetheme');

Route::delete('/theme/{id}/delete', 'ThemesController@destroy')->name('deletetheme');
```

I put every route regarding this topic in this question. So when I click on the link in my view:

`<a href="{{ route('showtopic', ['id' => $topic->id]) }}"`

I keep getting the error that I showed in the beginning of this question
I hope I made this clear enough for you to understand. Please inform me if I miss information that is needed in this question. Thanks in advance

**Theme.blade.php**

```
  <div class="col s12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-content"><span class="card-title"> - Topics</span>
                    <div class="collection">
                        @foreach($topics as $topic)
                            <a href="{{ route('showtopic', ['theme_id' => $theme->id, 'topic_id' => $topic->id]) }}" class="collection-item avatar collection-link"><img src="/uploads/avatars/{{ $topic->user->avatar }}" alt="" class="circle">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col s6">
                                        <div class="row last-row">
                                            <div class="col s12"><span class="title">Theme - {{ $topic->topic_title }}</span>
                                                <p>{!! str_limit($topic->topic_text, $limit = 125, $end = '...') !!}</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row last-row">
                                            <div class="col s12 post-timestamp">Posted by: {{ $topic->user->username }} op: {{  $topic->created_at }}</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col s2">
                                        <h6 class="title center-align">Replies</h6>
                                        <p class="center replies">{{ $topic->replies->count() }}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col s2">
                                        <h6 class="title center-align">Status</h6>
                                        <div class="status-wrapper center-align"><span class="status-badge status-open">open</span></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col s2">
                                        <h6 class="title center-align">Last reply</h6>
                                        <p class="center-align"></p>
                                        <p class="center-align">Tijd</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to give two different parameters name for your route parameter as

```
Route::get('/theme/{theme-id}/topics/{topic-id}', 'TopicsController@show')->name('showtopic');
```

and then pass the both parameters as

```
{{ route('showtopic', ['theme-id' => $theme->id, 'topic-id' => $topic->id]) }}
```

If you want to call your route with only one parameter, then make the second parameter as option in your route as

```
Route::get('/theme/{theme-id}/topics/{topic-id?}', 'TopicsController@show')->name('showtopic');
```

and then pass the both parameters as

```
{{ route('showtopic', ['theme-id' => $theme->id]) }}
```

Comment: It gives me the error that $theme is undefined in my theme.blade.php
Can you tell me how i can fix this? I updated my question so now the blade.php is in there

Comment: @feudelcosine148 at the time of calling your route, you are not passing `theme-id`. So how you can get it in your blade, better first check if the variable exist, then only use in your blade

Comment: I hope this makes it clear. http://imgur.com/a/sgoWj
And this is my web.php now: http://imgur.com/a/NQVu0

Answer (score 0):

To use the `route()` helper, rename `id` to:

```
Route::get('/theme/{themeId}/topics/{topicId}', 'TopicsController@show')->name('showtopic');
```

And because this route has two parameters, you need to pass both parameters:

```
{{ route('showtopic', ['themeId' => $theme->id, 'topicId' => $topic->id]) }}
```

Comment: I think your answer works but it shows me an error, 
`Undefined variable: theme` Because the $theme is not defined in this blade template. How can I solve this? I updated my question with the theme.blade.php

Comment: @feudelcosine148 well, change it to one with theme ID. If you don't have it yet, you should get it and pass to the view.

Comment: Can you show me an example? I don't quite understand what you mean